# Infinite smooth horizontal scroll without a plugin?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'd like to create an infinite side scrolling div without using extra plugins (besides jquery). I found this one: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

The problem is not only is it its own plugin, it also utilizes the jqueryUI... adding a bunch of code weight.

Here's what I have

```
<div id="columnWrapper">
    <div id="columnSlider">
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
       <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the javascript, I have a timer set to every 10 milliseconds, manipulating the left margin of the enitre #columnScroll by a few pixels each time.

```
var sliderInt=self.setInterval(function(){
    $('#columnSlider').css('margin-left',totalMargin);
    totalMargin -= .5;
},10);
```

What I really need is for the left side of #columnSlider and the right side of the same div to butt ends once the left side is off screen  (so that it scrolls sideways infinitely).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you amenable to a plugin if it doesn't require jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes definitely, as long as its dependable.

Comment: I'm going to attempt implementing Jamie's method today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this, it's actually a plugin I wrote to re-use but you can take it out of plugin form like below, you'll just need to add the correct elements and change element references, I think this is currently a vertical scroll too but - easy to change:

```
function initInfiniteScroll(){
var $carousel, $prevTrigger, $nextTrigger, itemHeight;
    $carousel = $('#alternate-views');
    $prevTrigger = $('.scroll-up');
    $nextTrigger = $('.scroll-down');
    itemHeight = 106;
    $allItems = $carousel.children().clone();
    $allItems.appendTo($carousel);
    $allItems.prependTo($carousel);

    $prevTrigger.click(function() {
        scrollCarousel('up');
        return false;
    });
    $nextTrigger.click(function() {
        scrollCarousel();
        return false;
    }); 

    function scrollCarousel(direction) {
        if (direction == 'up')
        {
            $carousel.animate({
                'top': '+=' + itemHeight
            },1000,function(){
                $carousel.children(':last').clone().prependTo($carousel);
                $carousel.children(':last').remove(); 
                $carousel.css({'top':'-' + itemHeight + 'px'});
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $carousel.animate({
                'top': '-=' + itemHeight
            },1000,function(){
                $carousel.children(':first').clone().appendTo($carousel);
                $carousel.children(':first').remove();  
                $carousel.css({'top':'-' + itemHeight + 'px'});
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This does clone the entire load and put it either side of the original scroller too - but you can remove this, also if you're using jquery 1.4+ you can take out the cloning and instead detach and re-add the items as you scroll.

Also - if you want to do a setTimeout, just use the content from the click function and put a timer around it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried doing it this way, but since I'm getting this strange graphic glitch. I'm moving the whole #columnSlider container my its margin, so once I remove the first item and append it, I need to set #columnSlider's margin back to 0... creating some funky graphic glitch.

Comment: Hi mate, notice the callback on the animate function resets the css for the carousel to 'top':'0' - if you're doing it horizontally (depending on which way your scrolling) this will need to be 'left':'0'. have you tried changing this?

Comment: Also if that doesn't work you can use negative margin's with it. See my latest blog post here www.japhex.net

Comment: I'll try again today. Thanks.

Comment: Got it to work using your plugin as a guide. The glitch is removed when you animate each column individually instead of doing so as a group.

Comment: Great - glad you got there mate, hopefully that blog post will help you understand exactly what's going on too. If this helped you I'd just ask that you accept my answer here :)